# Python Socket not sending data

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I'm currently working on a login server that can return user data to a computer that requests it. However it is not sending any data at all. Here are the parts of the code I think may be causing errors:

**Server**

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('127.0.0.1', 4876))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()

print('Connected: ' + addr[0])

data = conn.recv(1024)
print(addr[0] + ': ' + data)
data = data.split(' ')

if data[0] == 'rquser':
    print(addr[0] + ' requested user ' + data[1])
    users = open(read_settings()['local']['user_file'], 'r')
    users = json.load(users)
    user_found = (False, 0)
    print(addr[0] + ': searching... ')
    for x in range(len(users)):
        if users[str(x)]['username'] == data[1]:
            user_found = (True, x)
            break

    if user_found[0]:
        print(addr[0] + ': User found. ')
        conn.sendall(users[user_found[1]])
        conn.close()
```

**Client**

```
try:
    if read_settings()['local_users']:
        us = open(read_settings()['local']['user_file'], 'r')
        return json.load(us)
    else:
        if uid is None:
            raise ValueError
        else:
            s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            s.connect((read_network_settings()['server_ip'], 4876))
            message = 'rquser ' + uid
            s.sendall('rquser ' + uid)

            s_recv = ''
            data = s.recv(64)
            while True:
                data = s.recv(64)
                s_recv += data
                if not data:
                    break
            s.close()
            return s_recv
except IOError, socket.error:
    return None
```

I have made the server print out the status but it seems to stop at `Connected: 127.0.0.1`
I'm new to sockets in python and I've had little success with projects. But this one I can't understand why it's not working

Answer (score 2):

Instead of binding your server to `'127.0.0.1'`, use `''` as the first element of the tuple being passed to `bind`:

```
s.bind(('', 4876))
```

`''` will listen for any IP attempting to connect on the LAN.

Also, you should create a `while` loop in the server that on every iteration attempts to receive a connection, and if a connection has been received, do something with the client object:

```
while True:
  try:
     conn, addr = s.accept()
  except:
     pass
  else:
     #do something with conn
```